# How to test if the hostname given really exists?

Tags: java, dns

How do you test if the given hostname really exists in Java?

The problem is with some DNS services like Opendns which will return IP address even for non-existent DNS entries and, therefore, `InetAddress.getByName( host)` will always return something.

However, the `host` command is able to detect it somehow:

```
~$ host owqieyuqowiery.com
owqieyuqowiery.com has address 67.215.77.132
Host owqieyuqowiery.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Comment: does this project help? http://www.dnsjava.org/dnsjava-current/examples.html

Comment: if you can't trust the answers from OpenDNS - ** don't use them! **

Comment: @Alnitak That doesn't help since I do not control where is my software hosted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "really exists." Do you mean that it's a registered domain, with a website behind it? A host name is just a more easily readable/memorable form vs. an IP address for a given system. In other words, I could have a domain registered (which is just a publicly accessible short name for a system somewhere), and not host a website on a server that said domain points to, and that doesn't make the domain any less "real".

if you just want to lookup `A` records, here's a solution:

- Blog post: http://mowyourlawn.com/blog/?p=8
- Code: http://mowyourlawn.com/files/DomainRecord.java.txt

If you want to know what `host` does, which might shed some light on why it does what it does, there's some information on it here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/host Basically when this fails, it means the DNS lookup failed. That is, the DNS server(s) that `host` connected to in order to lookup that domain returned zero results.

Also, `host` returns more than just the DNS `A` record (which is what is used for websites). It will also give you MX (mail server) records, etc.

Ex:

```
$ host google.com
google.com has address 74.125.225.48
google.com has address 74.125.225.49
google.com has address 74.125.225.50
google.com has address 74.125.225.51
google.com has address 74.125.225.52
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
```

Comment: I basically need to know if it has A record in DNS.

Comment: Ah, I updated my answer to point to some example code that someone wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `InetAddress.getByName(address).isReachable(timeout);` instead.

Comment: This is a pretty straight forward way of doing it, but will only tell you if it's connect-able via ICMP request, or TCP connection on port 7, as opposed to telling you whether or not DNS records for the specified domain exist. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)

Comment: The thing is that isReachable will return true for any hostname, because it would test Opendns' servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot trust the locally configured resolver (perhaps because it lies about domains that don't exist) the only alternative is to *directly* query the *authoritative* name server(s) for the domain in question.

For Java this should be possible using the [`dnsjava`](http://www.dnsjava.org/) library.

You would need to start at the root name servers, and follow the referral chain down (in the same manner as a normal recursive server) to find the appropriate authoritative name server.

Comment: That's great advice. Do you have example code that does that using `dnsjava`?